# Yeoman: AngularJS & facebook SDK, page not loading

Tags: javascript, facebook, angularjs, yeoman, mean-stack

So im new with Angular and i downloaded the Yeoman scaffolding for Angular.JS to fiddle with it a bit.
I'm trying to implement Facebook Login with this library: https://github.com/pc035860/angular-easyfb
Nothing is loading and the console doesnt reflect anything. I'm almost sure the problem has something to do with the injecting of the facebook dependency on the controller.
I have this on my main.js file:

```
angular.module('circeApp', ['ezfb'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, ezfb, $window, $location) {
  updateLoginStatus(updateApiMe);

  $scope.login = function(){
  ezfb.login(function(response){
      if(response.authResponse){
      updateLoginStatus(updateApiMe);
      }
  }, {scope: 'email,user_likes'});
  };

  $scope.logout = function(){
  ezfb.logout(function(){
      updateLoginStatus(updateApiMe);
  });
  };

  function updateLoginStatus(more){
  ezfb.getLoginStatus(function(response){
      $scope.loginStatus = response;

      (more || anular.noop)();
  });
  }

  function updateApiMe(){
  ezfb.api('/me', function(response){
      $scope.apiMe = response;
  });
  }
});
```

And this on my app.js file:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('circeApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'ezfb'
])
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, ezfbProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/main',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/login',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      })
      .when('/signup', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/signup',
        controller: 'SignupCtrl'
      })
      .when('/settings', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/settings',
        controller: 'SettingsCtrl',
        authenticate: true
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', function($q, $location) {
      return {
        'responseError': function(response) {
          if(response.status === 401) {
            $location.path('/login');
            return $q.reject(response);
          }
          else {
            return $q.reject(response);
          }
        }
      };
    }]);
  })
  .run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {

    // Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {

      if (next.authenticate && !Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
        $location.path('/login');
      }
    });

//Configure ezfb provider aqui
   ezfbProvider.setInitParams({
       appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
       status: true,
       cookie: true,
       xfbml: true
   });
  });
```

Before this, the page rendered but console told me: "Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined". I fixed a missing parenthesis and made sure ezfb was included in angular.module. Now, the only thing i get is a blank page.

Comment: were you able to fix this? I guess I'm also stuck at the same place.

Comment: yeah, i stopped using ezfb and used passport.js :) its simpler in my opinion.
http://passportjs.org/